# ReactJS setting unique keys for resortable list elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a list GUI which can be re-arranged by drag and drop. Data comes from an existing API as an array of objects such as:

```
var dataFromApi = [
    {name: 'jack', label: 'Test element'},
    {name: 'john', label: 'Test element 2'}
];
```

There are many more properties per object, but there is no unique ID field for any object. The nature of data means that duplicate objects are permitted.

I used a React class to render these as a list:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: this.props.data
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ul>
            {
                this.state.data.map(function(item, idx) {
                    return (
                        <li>{item.name}</li>
                    );
                })
            }
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

I tried adding some drag-and-drop code, to allow the list to be re-ordered and the state to be updated accordingly. However, to re-order I need each `<li key={something?}>` element to have a unique key attribute which *isn't* the index.

What would be the best way add a unique key to each element, but *not* have this key in the data if I ever needed to send the changes up to a parent element - such as for saving the data to the server.

Comment: Why can't it be the `idx` for key? Is that specifically a constraint of the drag and drop code? That seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

try doing both, `<li key=idx+item>` think that would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Tried almost everything, setting the key as a combination of item properties and index, but nothing seemed to work if I wanted to allow re-arranging of child elements.

In the end I generated a random key for each object just after an API call which worked and allowed items to be re-arranged.

Comment: "generated a random key"? why not loop and assign the iteration value + listItemId?

Comment: Unfortunately the original items didn't have a unique ID tag of their own and often, items would be duplicated e.g. `{name: "john", label: "123"}, {name: "john", label: "123"}`. This is a common occurence. If I were to set the key to `key={item.name + i}` this would allow re-arranging of items, but then I'd have another issue when allowing the user to edit that field _and_ re-arrange the list.